# Hasse diagrams (2 options)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is it possible to draw more then one [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) for one/same [poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) ?
$$
R = \{(1,1);(2,2);(3,3);(4,4);(1,3);(1,4);(2,4);(3,4)\}
$$
There is no the smallest element, the greatest element is $4$.

Minimal elements are $1$, $2$.

Maximal element is $4$.

I drew two Hasse diagrams for this relation.

```
             4                                  4
           /   \                                |
          /     \                               |
         2       3            or                3
                /                              / \
               /                              /   \
             1                               1     2
```

Which of them is correct, and which not ? Where am I wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: $2R3$ is not true.

Comment: yes. you are right.